# after entering sh-4.2,nothing printed in the terminal

Tags: linux

Because I have forgotten my root' password.I edit 'e'.and I input init=/bin/sh.
after entering sh-4.2# mode,I input my command or some strings but I can't see nothing printed in the terminal.what  should I do to see commands I input in the terminal?Should I set anything?

Comment: It's most likely that your keyboard driver is not loaded properly by this approach. Another approach is to boot with a portable USB drive to change the password.

Comment: Can you type simple commands such as `ls`?  If not, then then as Anya suggested, there is likely a problem with your keyboard driver.  You might want to check out https://grml.org/ for an easy to use recovery USB.

If `ls` does work, but you can't use `vi`, try `export TERM=vt100` and see whether that helps.